# How to record a load scenario(performance script) through mobile browser in LoadComplete performance tool?

Tags: performance, mobile, performance-testing

How to record a load scenario(performance script) through mobile browser in LoadComplete?
Load Complete by default allows recording traffic through web browsers IE, Firefox and Chrome and stimulate it on various mobile browsers.
I want to record the load scenario through mobile browser, can anyone please provide their valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure proxy of LoadComplete Machine on your Mobile Device on the same port where LoadComplete is configured to record your test.

Start Recording in LoadComplete.

Once you're done, Open Mobile Browser and use the application, you should see your recordings in LoadComplete.

All the Best!